# Drawing an Arc2D.Float through inheritance

Tags: java, swing

So I have a class that inherits Arc2D.Float:

```
package Simon;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class SimonLight extends Arc2D.Float implements ActionListener{

    public Color defCol, lightUpCol, color; //Colors
    public enum Orientation {leftU, leftD, rightU, rightD};
    Orientation orient;

    public SimonLight(Color defCol, Color lightUpCol, Orientation orient, int x, int y){
        super.x = x;
        super.y = y;
        super.width = 200;
        super.height = 200;
        super.start = 90;
        super.extent = 90;
        this.defCol = defCol;
        this.color = defCol;
        this.lightUpCol = lightUpCol;
        this.orient = orient;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //Does nothing atm
        color = lightUpCol;
    }
    public Color getColor(){
        return color;
    }
}
```

But in the constructor, I am trying to set the arc type to Arc2D.PIE , but there is no variable in the super class to allow me to change it. Does anyone know how to set the type??

Comment: Perhaps you should be using use the `super` constructor instead of modifying the fields directly...

Comment: Ahhh.. didn't even think of that. I'm still a little new to using the keyword super! You can post the answer if you'd like ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using the `super` constructor instead...

```
public SimonLight(Color defCol, Color lightUpCol, Orientation orient, int x, int y){
    super(x, y, 200, 200, 90, 90, Arc2D.PIE);
    this.defCol = defCol;
    this.color = defCol;
    this.lightUpCol = lightUpCol;
    this.orient = orient;
}
```

This is generally a better practice, in case the super class requires these values to set itself up internally ;)